# What happens next if a question is unanswered after the bounty is dropped and is removed from the featured list?

Tags: discussion

Thanks to Brandon Enright for putting the question "[Is there a field equation which can reduce into all three flavors of spin (zero, one, one half)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98513/is-there-a-field-equation-which-can-reduce-into-all-three-flavors-of-spin-zero)" on the featured list by placing a bounty on it. Since the bounty ran out, the question is no longer on the featured list and still remains unanswered. What is the next evolutionary stage of the question? Will it be cast into the sea of forgotten unanswered questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stays open. You can put another bounty on it if you wish, though it is advisable to try and improve the question.

Being "cast into the sea of forgotten unanswered questions" isn't something done deliberately, it just happens. But these do get found and answered, if good, eventually.

Comment: I would be willing to put a bounty on it if I had more reputation. Once I put the bounty, I will never get it back. It would be awesome if one could pay a small reputation fee and cast one's bounty and get some of it back if the question is unanswered for sometime.

Comment: @linuxfreebird But I believe the reputation spent on the bounty is lost regardless, even if there is no answer to which it gets awarded. Something to think about.

Comment: Think of it as an advertisement rather than a bounty.

Comment: If the bounty was (partially) refunded, people could hold the same questions in the featured list for a very long time. The current system forces you to think twice, and that's a good thing.